# In SparQL, how to distinguish a year like 2017, and January 1st, 2017?

Tags: datetime, sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api

The following SPARQL queries using [Wikidata](http://query.wikidata.org)'s [REST API](https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) both return a date, of type `xsd:datetime`, on January 1st:

```
>>> # Inception of Manchester United F.C. = in 1875
>>> wikidata_rest_query("SELECT ?date WHERE { wd:Q18656 wdt:P571 ?date }")
{'head': {'vars': ['date']},
 'results': {'bindings': [{'date': {'datatype': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime',
     'type': 'literal',
     'value': '1875-01-01T00:00:00Z'}}]}}

>>> # Istanbul nightclub attack = on January 1st 2017
>>> wikidata_rest_query("SELECT ?date WHERE { wd:Q28094271 wdt:P585 ?date }")
{'head': {'vars': ['date']},
 'results': {'bindings': [{'date': {'datatype': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime',
     'type': 'literal',
     'value': '2017-01-01T00:00:00Z'}}]}}
```

In the first case, the date just means "*in 1875*", not literally on January 1st 1875 at midnight. In the second case, the date actually means "*on January 1st 2017*", but not specifically at midnight. I would have preferred responses like "1875" and "2017-01-01".

When browsing the Wikidata pages for these topics ([Manchester United F.C.](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q18656) and [2017 Istanbul Night Club Attack](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q28094271)), the correct level of detail is displayed (i.e., 1875 in the first case, but January 1st, 2017 in the second), so they must have the correct information in their database, and hopefully there is a way to query it.

Any ideas?

**Note**

I tried querying `datatype(?date)`, hoping to see a difference, but it returns `xsd:datetime` in both examples.

**Edit**

Here's the python 3 code of `wikidata_rest_query()`, if you want to test the queries above:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, quote
import json

def wikidata_rest_query(query):
    url = "https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=%s&format=json" % quote(query)
    with urlopen(url) as f:
        response = f.read().decode("utf-8")
    return json.loads(response)
```

Comment: The backend (Blazegraph) maybe returns all data values as `xsd:dateTime` although internally some values are indeed of type `xsd:date` - but that's just a guess.

Comment: Indeed, my fear is that they have the data, but they're returning wrong. Perhaps there's a way to query `type(?date)` so I can fix the issue on the client side?

Comment: I just found a solution, check out my answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Wikidata solved this problem by storing additional information about each `xsd:datetime`, in particular the `timePrecision`:

```
>>> query = """
... SELECT ?time ?timeprecision ?timezone ?timecalendar WHERE {
...     wd:Q18656 p:P571/psv:P571 ?timenode.
...     ?timenode wikibase:timeValue         ?time.
...     ?timenode wikibase:timePrecision     ?timeprecision.
...     ?timenode wikibase:timeTimezone      ?timezone.
...     ?timenode wikibase:timeCalendarModel ?timecalendar.
... }
... """
>>> wikidata_rest_query(query)
{'head': {'vars': ['time', 'timeprecision', 'timezone', 'timecalendar']},
 'results': {'bindings': [{'time': {'datatype': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime',
     'type': 'literal',
     'value': '1875-01-01T00:00:00Z'},
    'timecalendar': {'type': 'uri',
     'value': 'http://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q1985727'},
    'timeprecision': {'datatype': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer',
     'type': 'literal',
     'value': '9'},
    'timezone': {'datatype': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer',
     'type': 'literal',
     'value': '0'}}]}}
```

The `timePrecision` is equal to 9, which means *year*. The other possible precisions are [listed here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/WIKIDATA_Precision,_Units_and_Coordinates#Time):

> The codes for precision are 0: billion years, 1: hundred million
>   years, 3: million years, 4: hundred thousand years, 5: ten thousand
>   years, 6: millennium, 7: century, 8: decade, 9: year, 10: month, 11:
>   day, 12: hour, 13: minute, 14: second.

If you try the Istanbul query, you will get a `timePrecision` equal to 11: day, as expected.

It would sure be simpler if we could just write `timePrecision(?date)`, but that's life, and at least we have a solution.